# Not Able to create Registry key

Tags: c#

I tried the below code to create Registry Key. but not successfull.

```
Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\MyKey", Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
```

Even this command is not returning any Exception.
I need help on this

Thanks 
skharod

Comment: If you don't get an error, it's possible that you are looking in the wrong place in the registry. If your code is 32 bits on a 64-bit system, some registry keys are redirected.

Comment: If you don't get an exception then you *know* that the key got created.  Look in Software\Wow6432Node instead.

Comment: Beat you with a second, Hans ;)

Comment: hay Hans; Thanks . it worked that ways.. Thanks Again . but dnt know how to mark a comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't get an exception then you know that the key got created.

Look in Software\Wow6432Node instead

Answer (score 1):

You need administrator privileges to create a key in Local Machine.. Perhaps you should try running the application as administrator..